# Problem with Passing both single and double quote via subprocess?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

So the original command i wanted to pass is -

`runuser -l chrome -c 'DISPLAY= /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host --code="4/yourcode" --redirect-url="https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect" --name=VastInstance'`

And i tried two ways. First one is-

````
def pcall(pram):
    s.run([pram], shell=True)

pcall("runuser -l raiyan -c 'DISPLAY= /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host --code=\"4/0AY0e-g6DezhppO-9eF6BCGahZOOxN-Rs2uG0lm-G0FRIL1PvLR22-oqnCBHGmVUjr86o2A\" --redirect-url=\"https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect\" --name=Raiyan\'s PC' --pin=000000") ```  
      

where pcall is a function that calls subprocess.run() and the error says ```/bin/sh: 1: Syntext error: Unterminated quoted string.```

So i tried another way - ```s.run({'runuser','-l,'raiyan','-c','DISPLAY=','/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host','--code=','4/SomeCode','--redirect-url=','https://remotedesktop.google.com/\_/oauthredirect','--name=','raiyan'])``` 

And this also show Syntex error right here
>https:// remotedesktop.google .com/\➡️_/⬅️oauthredirect
````

I'm absolutely clueless about what to do here.
[And i also don't understand why the code tag is not working here :(   ]

Comment: Why not use [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html)?

Comment: Honestly, i didn't know this existed. Is shlex more efficient than subprocess?

Comment: `shlex` doesn't run anything, but it will split up your command the same way a shell would so that you can pass it to `subprocess.run`. You can try it out with `shlex.split("""runuser -l ....""")` and see that it splits it up into 5 arguments, while you split it up into 12 (causing it to fail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using triple quotes so you don't have to escape any in the command.

```py
pcall("""runuser -l chrome -c 'DISPLAY= /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host --code="4/yourcode" --redirect-url="https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect" --name=VastInstance'""")
```

Comment: ```File "<ipython-input-4-367a8ac28089>", line 60
    pcall(""" runuser -l raiyan -c 'DISPLAY= /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host --code="4/SomeCode" --redirect-url="https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect" --name=Raiyans PC --pin=000000' """)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: @IsitiakMahmud It's hard to tell from what you shared here but I think the syntax issue is on a different line, it's most likely not related to the string or function call directly. If you could share more of your code it might become clearer what the issue is.

Comment: I did edit out my code but it seems i can't code it properly.